# How to get testfile to outputstream flowfile in nifi executescript processor

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I am trying to write a text file that contains dictionary to outputStream callback in Nifi ExcuteScript processor . Here is my code, but it doesn't work as expected -

```
import json
import java.io
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
import os
import java.io.FileOutputStream

ofile=open("/home/nifi/data/outfile.txt", 'a')
with open("/home/nifi/data/validation.json",'r') as vfile:
    validation = json.loads(vfile.read())
finaldict={}
dict1={}

class ModJSON(StreamCallback):
  def __init__(self):
        pass
  def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
    text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    invalidrecord = json.loads(text)

    for record in invalidrecord:
        #print(finaldict)
        finaldict.update(record)
        # print(finaldict)
        finaldict['errors'] = []
        errordict = {}
        # loop through each field from validation json
        for field in validation:
            for element, value in record.items():
                if field == element:
                    dtype = type(value)
                    dict1 = validation[field]
                    for validtype in dict1:
                        if validtype['validationType'] == 'datatype':
                            if str(dtype) == validtype['check']:
                                pass
                            else:
                                errordict = {"element": field}
                                errordict.update({"errorCode": validtype['errorCode']})
                                finaldict["errors"].append(errordict)
                        if validtype['validationType'] == 'maxlength':
                            dlen = len(str(value))
                            if str(dlen) <= str(validtype['check']):
                                pass
                            else:
                                errordict = {"element": field}
                                errordict.update({"errorCode": validtype['errorCode']})
                                finaldict["errors"].append(errordict)
                else:
                    pass
        json.dump(finaldict, ofile)

    outputStream.write(bytearray(ofile.encode('utf-8')))

flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
  flowFile = session.write(flowFile, ModJSON())
  flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "filename", flowFile.getAttribute('filename').split('.')[0]+'_translated.json')
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
session.commit()
```

In above code, `outputStream.write(bytearray(ofile.encode('utf-8')))` is not writing outfile.txt to flowfile and throwing:

> NullPointerException at session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)

Can someone please suggest what is wrong with these code.

Related question is in below link, but couldn't find what i am looking for, as it does not send the text_file to flowfile output of nifi.

[Access Json element and write to a text file using python ExecuteScript processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630612/access-json-element-and-write-to-a-text-file-using-python-executescript-processo?rq=1)

Comment: you are opening file for writing `ofile=open("/home/nifi/data/outfile.txt", 'a')` and try to read it: `bytearray(ofile.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Tried adding below lines at line no. 53 -

Comment: nfile=open("/home/nifi/data/outfile.txt", 'r')
 outputStream.write(bytearray(nfile.encode('utf-8')))     but still does not work

Comment: Also tried,  nfile=open("/home/nifi/data/outfile.txt", 'r')
 n=nfile.read()
 outputStream.write(bytearray(json.dumps(n, sort_keys= True, indent=4).encode('utf-8')))     but again nullpointer exception

Comment: please add to your question the full stack trace from the log file

Comment: session transfer and commit must be under `if (flowFile != None):`